# Disable Point Marks and Item Labels in WPF RadChart

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radchart

How can I turn off Point Marks and Item Labels in WPF RadChart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this;

```
<telerik:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
    <telerik:LineSeriesDefinition ShowItemLabels="False" ShowPointMarks="False"/>
</telerik:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do by setting `SeriesDefinition.ShowItemLabels` property to `false` look at below code:

```
var smartSeriesMapping = new SeriesMapping
{
    LegendLabel = "smartSeries",
    SeriesDefinition = new LineSeriesDefinition()
};
smartSeriesMapping.ItemMappings.Add(new ItemMapping("Time", DataPointMember.XCategory));
smartSeriesMapping.ItemMappings.Add(new ItemMapping("SmartVal", DataPointMember.YValue));
smartSeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition.ShowItemLabels = false; //This line make lables go away :D

SmsRadChart.SeriesMappings.Add(smartSeriesMapping);
```